# php how to scrape inside <li><a> using simplehtmldom?

Tags: php, list, loops, foreach, scrape

HTML from site

```
    <ul id="blahlist">
    <li><a href="http://blahblah.com">blah blah</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blahblah2.com">blah blah 2</a></li>
    ......
    </ul>
```

my code

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load_file( "blah.html" );

    $div_category = $dom->find("#blahlist");

    foreach ($div_category as &$ul){
    $a_list = $ul->find("a");
    foreach ( $a_list as &$anchor){
        $csv_array=array($anchor->plaintext, $anchor->getAttribute("href") );
        fputcsv($csv_out, $csv_array);
        print_r($anchor);
    }
```

the problem is it only show the first row(first line) and not showing the rest of the list within blahlist. Am I doing something wrong? something to do with `<li>` that might have stopped after the first line?

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$dom->find("#blahlist li");
```

It is to "grab" all `li`s *under* `#blahlist`.

Comment: I think you should elaborate some more, not everyone knows `DOM`.

Comment: @Moe Sweet I just tried it and still same result. Can you explain what you mean elaborate it more Im not sure what i can put for those who knows DOM?

Comment: @Truth this is not DOM but SimpleHTMLDom. SimpleHTMLDom has nothing to do with with DOM. DOM is a W3C language agnostic interface and SimpleHTMLDom does not implement it.

Comment: @Truth yes, I assumed that, but its not what the OP is using. PHP's DOM extension is an implementation of the W3C interface. And it doesnt have a find method, nor does it support CSS Selector queries.

Comment: Which is why I said he should elaborate, I'm one of those clueless who will make that mistake :P

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate `simple_html_dom();` is. `"#blahlist li"` is a simple selector, it should be handled well. If there's a chance you could switch to another library, I recommend querypath.org. It works for me.

Comment: @Moe Sweet sorry guys I just updated my post when he ask to elaborate it. I added 'simpleHTMLDom' to my code after his comment. I might try querypath.org but Im much more comfortable using simplehtmlDom and hope to be able to grab everything in li

Answer (score 1):

Scrape using regular expressions:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<ul id="blahlist">
    <li><a href="http://blahblah.com">blah blah</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blahblah2.com">blah blah 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blahblah2.com">blah blah 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blahblah2.com">blah blah 4</a></li>
</ul>
EOF;

$ul_id = "blahlist";

if (preg_match("#<ul[^<>]+id=[\"']?{$ul_id}[\"']?[^<>]*>([\s\S]+?)</ul>#i", $html, $match)) 
{
    $lis = $match[1];
    preg_match_all("#<li[^<>]*>\s*<a[^<>]+href=[\"']?([^<>\"']+)[\"']?[^<>]*>([\s\S]+?)</a>#i", $lis, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $href) {
        $href = strip_tags($href);
        $text = strip_tags($matches[2][$k]);
        print "$text [$href]<br>";
    }
}
```

You just edit the id of the ul list on this line:

```
$ul_id = "blahlist";
```

Result:

```
blah blah [http://blahblah.com]
blah blah 2 [http://blahblah2.com]
blah blah 3 [http://blahblah2.com]
blah blah 4 [http://blahblah2.com]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I prefer loading to simpleHTMLDom instead of regular expression. The reason is because my next function will grab everything inside the url and so forth from reading the csv thats created from this function I posted it. If there is a way maybe Im more comfortable using Dom over regex.